# Twitter API not working

Tags: iphone, ios4, twitter, mgtwitterengine

issue during implementing twitter API.
when i send a request using 
http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml

i got a message

Basic authentication is not supported

Can anyone provide me some sample examples of implementing twitter api.?

Comment: `Can anyone provide me some sample examples of implementing twitter api.?` I can google the answer in less than 30 seconds, what about you? -> http://dev.twitter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twitter no more supports `basic authentication`, you'll have to implement `OAuth authentication` in order to retrieve `secure` data from twitter.

here is an article to help you getting started with twitter OAuth in `C#` and `iPhone`  respectively

http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone